# Linq between dates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

So i have a query that is getting data correctly but as soon as I try to filter out the linq statement with a where between dates, I consistently get zero results.

```
        var query= Enumerable.Empty<CustomClass>().AsQueryable();

        query= (from auto in db.AutoInvs
            join deal in db.Deals on new { inv = auto.INVUID, client = auto.CLIENTID, acct = auto.ACCOUNT} equals new {inv = deal.INVUID,client = deal.CLIENTID, acct = (int?) deal.ACCOUNT}
            join dmCust in db.DMCusts on new {inv = auto.INVUID, client = auto.CLIENTID, acct = auto.ACCOUNT.ToString()} equals  new {inv = dmCust.INVUID, client = dmCust.CLIENTID, acct = dmCust.ACCOUNT} 
            join act in db.Acts on new { inv = auto.INVUID, client = auto.CLIENTID, acct = auto.ACCOUNT.ToString()} equals new { inv = act.INVUID, client = act.CLIENTID, acct = act.Key }
            where auto.DATAPROCESSEDDATE == null && auto.INVUID != "" 
            select new CustomClass()
            {
                AutoInv = auto,
                Deal = deal,
                DmCust = dmCust,
                Act = act
            });
    var filteredData = query.Where(c => c.AutoInv.DATESOLD >= dateFrom.Value && c.AutoInv.DATESOLD <= dateTo.Value).AsQueryable();
    Console.WriteLine(filteredData.ToList().Count);
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. Only one line of code is relevant here, and your input data and datetime values are missing.

Comment: I suspect auto.DATAPROCESSEDDATE is never null.  DateTime object cannot be null.  So I would try auto.DATAPROCESSEDDATE.year < 1980.  The default DateTime object is 1900.

Answer (score 3):

Using this stripped down version (and my own data), it works for me:

```
var query = Enumerable.Empty<Tbl1>().AsQueryable();

DateTime? dateFrom = new DateTime(2017, 5, 10);
DateTime? dateTo = new DateTime(2017, 5, 20);

query = (from auto in db.Tbl1s
         select auto);

var filteredData = query.Where(c => c.StartDate >= dateFrom.Value 
                                 && c.StartDate <= dateTo.Value).AsQueryable();
filteredData.Dump();
```

One possible problem you may be having is that `dateTo` would be the *exclusive* end point --- Unless `DATESOLD` is exactly midnight, you won't get any that are on the end date.